# Powershell script works in Server 2016 if I run it manually but it dsn't work when I try to run it with the php command

Tags: php, powershell, csv, active-directory, windows-server-2016

Hi everyone I have a ps1 file about password reset from AD.It works in Servr 2016 if I run it manually but it dsn't work when I try to run it with the php command i share php , ps1, csv file can you help me ?

index.php=>

```
function powershellpasswordreset(){
  $output2 = Shell_Exec ('powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -Command "C:\www\passwordreset.ps1"'); }
```

passwordreset.ps1=>

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory --Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
$csv = import-csv C:\www\PasswordReset.csv
$csv | ForEach-Object {
$SecPaswd= ConvertTo-SecureString –String $.newpassword –AsPlainText –Force -- 
Set-ADAccountPassword Reset -NewPassword $SecPaswd 
–Identity $.samaccountname -- Set-ADUser
–Identity $_.samaccountname –ChangePasswordAtLogon $false -- }
exit
```

PasswordReset.csv =>

```
samaccountname,newpassword
test,3432*Test'
```

Comment: Any error messages? Don't forget PHP, when executed via a web application, runs under a different user account than your own personal account, and may have different privileges. I would expect that resetting an AD password would require a privileged account

Comment: i havent any error messages. I run it with domain admin accounts. When I write the command to create a new text file in the ps1 file and run it from php, it creates the file.Most likely AD does not allow for password change.AD does not allow for password change even though I am Domain Admins account.